# How to use a switch with a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, switch-statement

I have multiple pages that call a 'featured items' list - I would like to have the featured items in an include and then on my other pages just give the names of which featured items to include  in a variable.

I thought maybe using a switch and then a foreach loop to run through it all but I'm new to PHP and I'm not sure thats the right thing to do.

So I wanted to create my switch like so:

```
switch ($sector){
    case "Sector1":
        $title = "title of sector";
        $url = "url here";
        $img = "image url here";       
        break;
    case "Sector2":
        $title = "title of sector";
        $url = "url here";
        $img = "image url here";
        break;
    case "Sector3":
        $title = "title of sector";
        $url = "url here";
        $img = "image url here";
        break;    
    default:
        $title = "title of sector";
        $url = "url here";
        $img = "image url here";
        break;
}
```

and then on each page I'd like to declare which switch(es) I'd like to use

So for example I'd like to use sector 1 and 2 and then run them in a foreach loop so they output something like:

```
<div class="item">
    <h1>'.$title.'</h1>
    <img src="'.$img.'" />
</div>
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you using a db? If not, it seems like you need it

Comment: There is only 4/5 items that I'll be switching between so I thought I could just put it in a switch case instead.

Comment: Do they change? If not, dont waste your time, just  write directly the HTML.

Comment: You are on right track. create function for section switch part. return array from it. call function by passing sector argument and use return array to render block of html.

Comment: wonderwhy - I'd prefer to use php as I have 10 pages that call different 'featured items' - plus it would be good to learn how to do it :) kayra - thanks for the tip although I'm not entirely sure how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason for using a switch case. Just declared your items in an array, as so:

```
$Sectors = array("Sector1" => array("title" => "title of sector", "url" => "url here", "img" = "image url here"), 
  "Sector2" => array(...), 
 ...);
```

Then you can get any particular value like

```
$Sectors["Sector1"]["title"]
```

Then you can either just code the exact html tags on each page, or have like a generic page and at the top have an array for which you want to use like

```
$Sectors_to_use = ["Sector1", "Sector2"];
foreach $Sectors_to_use as $sector {
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo  "<h1>" . $Sectors[$sector]["title"] . "</h1>";
    echo  '<img src="' . $Sectors[$sector]["img"] . '"' />;
    echo "</div>"
}
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me! I had to change the $Sectors_to_use = ["Sector1", "Sector2"]; to $Sectors_to_use = array("Sector1", "Sector2"); as it didn't like the square brackets but you really helped me - thanks! :)